# Split view / hamburger menu inside navigation controller on iphone

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I am looking for control or approach, that would allow to embed two view controllers to present menu-like behaviour, but inside navigation controller. Examples are below:

[image: Split view showing only detail]
[image: Split view showing master and detail]

Comment: There are dozens of these controls on GitHub, have you searched there?  Or do you want to code your own?

Comment: Well I have tried some, most popular. The problem is that they mostly inherit from NSSplitView or UISplitViewController, so that it can't be embedded in navigation controller and mostly wants to do some mess around navigation bar, which is not the case here.

I can do it my own, but... I wonder what is better: uicollectionview with some custom layout? just scroll view with two view controllers (by the way - is it possible in storyboard?)? or maybe some other solution?